# How do I run multiple javascripts in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-instances

I'm having this problem with my site.  I'm trying to get 2 scripts to run on the same page but one will not work unless I delete either:

```
<script src="js/jquery.op.loc.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Here is the javascript code I have inserted into the  section of my page:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.op.loc.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.op.loc.min.css" />

   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#default-usage .to-lock").loc({
            text: {
                header: "How are you today?",
                message: "Hello!"
            },
            theme: "secrets",
            buttons: {
                order: ["twitter-tweet", "facebook-like", "google-plus"]
            },
            twitter: {
                tweet: {
                    url: "http://twitter.com",
                    text: "tweet!"
                }
            },
            facebook: {
                like: {
                    url: "http://facebook.com"
                },
                appId: "427542137301809"
            },
            google: {
                plus: {
                    url: "http://google.com"
                }
            }
        });
    });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php if($network == "") {echo '';} elseif($network == "") {echo '';} echo $account_id; ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("div.process").fadeOut(0);
      $("input.button").click(function() {
        $('div.process div.bar').css("width", "0%");
        $("div.process").fadeOut(0);
        $("span.status span").empty();
        $("span.status span").append("On hold");
        $("span.status").css("color", "#FF0000");
        var urlform = $("input.profile").val();
        $.post("<?php echo $filename; ?>?post=1", {url:urlform}, function(data) {
          var exploded = data.split('||');
          var profileimage = exploded[0];
          var profilename = exploded[1];
          if(profilename !== "") {
            $("img.profileimg").attr("src", profileimage);
            $("span.profilename span").empty();
            $("span.profilename span").append(profilename);
            $("span.status span").empty();
            $("span.status span").append("Searching for account");
            $("span.status").css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $("div.process").fadeIn("2000");
            $('div.process div.bar').animate({
              width: "200px"
            }, 14000, function() {
              $("span.status span").empty();
              $("span.status span").append("Account found");
              $("span.status").css("color", "#33FF00");
              setTimeout(function() {startGateway('<?php echo $widget_id; ?>');}, 500);
            });
          } else {
            $("span.status span").empty();
            $("span.status span").append("Account not found!");
            $("span.status").css("color", "#FF0000");
            $("img.profileimg").attr("src", "img/blank.jpg");
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I am a complete newbie when it comes to javascript so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please elaborate .Why you need two scripts.there must be some conflicting  in these two ?

Comment: This depends entirely on the content of those two files. jquery-latest I'm familiar with but what is this op.loc thing? Generally, you want to include the jQuery framework only once, and any subsequent plugin after that.

Comment: just try after moving `jQuery.min.js` at first to get loaded in the page or you can make use of `closure` _`iife`_

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

1. Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file else in the html head section
2. Be sure that you've included the other scripts after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
3. Check whether jQuery is included properly and once only.
4. Watch out for jQuery conflicts. There is some other library which is overridding $, so your code is not working because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore. You can use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable $.